# How do I properly create and reference host groups in Ansible?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, ansible, yaml

I'm developing a patching solution that will drain a node, install all available Windows patches, and set the node back to active, one at a time. In our environment, our manager nodes are running Linux and our worker nodes are running Windows because the applications we need to run are not compatible with Linux. The first piece I'm trying to get working is to be able to issue the drain command to the manager node referencing a worker node, but I'm definitely doing something wrong at the moment.

Here's what my playbook looks like currently:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  serial: 1 #to make sure we are only hitting a single worker node at a time

  tasks: 
    - name: drain worker node
      shell: docker node update --availability drain "{{ workernode }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ managernode }}" #run drain command from management node
      become: true
```

I also have an inventory that looks like this:

```ini
[managernode]
FBLDKRDEVLD08.develop.fcbt

[workernode]
FBLDKRDEVWD02.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD03.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD04.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD05.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD09.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD10.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD11.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD12.develop.fcbt
FBLDKRDEVWD13.develop.fcbt
```

This is the error I receive

> fatal: [FBLDKRDEVLD08.develop.fcbt -> {{ managernode }}]: FAILED! =>
> {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The
> error was: 'workernode' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/runner/project/ansible/Server Tasks/Swarm_Patching_Test.yml': line
> 8, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name:
> drain worker node\n      ^ here\n"}

This playbook works if I reference each node by name, but not when I attempt to reference by group.

Comment: You might want to hold off w `serial:1 `. You could just have all hosts in the play at once. Because you want to set a host in downtime, and then verify in another system that it's actually in downtime.

Comment: If I didn't add ```serial:1```, wouldn't all hosts be executed against at the same time? The idea is to execute against 1 node at a time; drain node, run patching, set node back to active, then move onto the next.

Comment: Yes. But create groups or use ‘when’

Answer (score 0):

Any host of a group, can be accessed thanks to the [`groups`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-groups) special variable, which is a dictionary of lists where the keys are the name of all your hosts groups and the lists represent all the hosts of the corresponding groups.

So, in your case: `groups.managernode.0` — `.0` being the first element of a zero-indexed list of hosts in the group named `managernode`, in this case.

With this, your `delegate_to` becomes

```yaml
delegate_to: "{{ groups.managernode.0 }}"
```

---

But, in this case, you could also give a [friendly alias](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases) to your *"manager node"* host and move its real connection name / IP into `ansible_host`, in your inventory:

```ini
[managernode]
manager_node ansible_host=FBLDKRDEVLD08.develop.fcbt
```

Then, in your playbook, you can use:

```yaml
delegate_to: manager_node
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but ideally rather than individually listing/enumerating each host (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) it would go through the list of worker nodes and execute 1 by 1. This way I could change what hosts are being executed against as well as the number of hosts and not run into an issue. Or would that not be a problem with this solution? Again, I'm pretty new to Ansible so I greatly appreciate any additional context on this. Thanks again.